# Postman send both data in json and image

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have created one API and it is adding data in database, with values and image.

In postman I am calling that and setting image in form-data and other values in raw in JSON but still in image I am getting null value in source code object. Below are screenshots.

I want help in two things :

1. Why I am getting Null in image value in source code, please check below image.
2. How can I send both image and data using postman, check below screenshots is that ok what I have tried ?

First screenshot is of postman in which I am sending data in json format :

[image]

Second screenshot is of postman in which I am sending image in same request in postman

[image]

Now in third image you can see in Image it is showing Null instead of values.

[image]

So I am not getting why image is coming null..Below is code for this

```
public async Task<int> Create(UserPreference _object)
{
   if(_object.Image != null)
   {
       var webRootPath = hostingEnv.WebRootPath;
       var fileName = Path.GetFileName(_object.Image.FileName);
       var filePath = Path.Combine(hostingEnv.WebRootPath, "images\\User", fileName);

       using(var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
       {
          await _object.Image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
       }

       _object.ImagePath = filePath;
   }
   
   var obj = await applicationDbContext.UserPreferences.AddAsync(_object);
   return applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

[image]

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("CreateUserPreference")]
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateUserPreference([FromBody] UserPreference userPreference)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      try
      {
         var userPreferenceId = await _userPreference.Create(userPreference);
         if (userPreferenceId > 0)
             return Ok("User Preference has added");
      }
      catch(Exception)
      {
         return BadRequest();
      }
  }
  return BadRequest();
}


 [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public string Location { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "About Me")]
        public string AboutMe { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Match Preference")]
        public string MatchPreference { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Play Score")]
        public string PlayScore { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "Location")]
        public string LocationPreference { get; set; } = "";

        [Display(Name = "CreatedOn"), DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

        [Display(Name ="Upload Photo")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; } = "";
        
        [NotMapped]
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, did it send picture in postman in second image you attached? Another question I have is that did you defined your class for received data correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send image and data using Postman you have to use form-data content type.

Select body => form-data. Column key has a selector. For a file select file-type and select file. To send data in the same time you will have to separate your json in key value pair.

And remove [FromBody] attribute from the action. It is only used for Content-Type: application/json, but yours Content-Type: multipart/form-data;

Comment: I have tried in that way but still getting error "title": "Unsupported Media Type",

Comment: @Nic Can you pls post the picture of form-data tab of Postman? You don't need to fill all keys for the test . a couple would be enough

Comment: I have added screenshot at the end of question..you can check it.

Comment: @Nic Thanks, but it calls CreateUserPreference action not Create. Can you post it pls? The header would be enough

Comment: I have added that method..please check it

Comment: @Nic Remove [FromBody] , it is used only for json, not for key value pairs

Comment: I have added my model class also, please check is that correct

Comment: I am still getting that same error.

Comment: @Nic Try to add [FromForm] but I am not sure if it works, it depends on net version.

Comment: @Nic I just tested your model and it works without [FromForm]. I am using net core.

Comment: means you are able to get image values and all other values

Comment: @Nic Yes. I don't have any media errors and data is filled. I didn't test your code inside  of the action since it is out of the scope of the question

Comment: ok..let me check again

Comment: it worked with FromForm

Answer (score 5):

Postman **allows** to POST mixed data types as Multipart/form-data, you *just* need to select the option to display the Content Type :
[image: select your data type in Postman]

then you can use a controller (example here in java) :

```
@PostMapping(value = "store/template", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE}) 
public void createDocumentTemplate(@Valid @RequestPart("templateRequest") TemplateDto request, @Valid @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {

        storeYourFileAccordingToYourRequest(request, file);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]You cannot send both form-data and JSON body at the same time
To solve your problem send image and your other information as form-date
For more details see the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Postman doesn't allow you to send two different form types at the same time like that. In your question is either sending the JSON payload *or* the binary content of your image.

So instead, add both the file *and* the JSON payload to the form-data screen, like this:

[image]

Postman will automatically set the `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW` header and then handle the actually body like this:

```
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="/C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/hystrix-dashboard-netflix-api-example-iPad.png"
Content-Type: image/png

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
```

Answer (score 0):

[**ASP.NET CORE FRAMEWORK**]

Suppose you want to send a file (image) inside the body request including more properties in the same body. In that case, I strongly recommend using the attribute [FromForm] before your object parameter in your API. Like the example below:

[image: Beginning of API declaration in .net core]

Then if you want to test your API via post-man you **must** use body with form-data type. For your file/image give the property name and select 'File' type on the key side, and on the value side, select the file by clicking 'Select Files', do the same for the other properties, key = property name, and value for their values (being string, double ... and so on). Like the example below:

[image: Post-man example of HTTP POST with a file inside the body.]